# Animate a foreach loop with tikz in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, animate

I'm currently trying to animate how does a convolutionnal filter (and so, a convolution operation over a 2D array) is working.
To do that and inspired from this work : https://github.com/vdumoulin/conv_arithmetic
I have achieved most of the work with tikz but I have no idea about how to do the animation with animate package in combination with tikz illustration.

My code is there (note that at this point, I only perform the foreach loop with x in the range of 0 to 5):

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},xcolor=table,t, compress]{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false, compress]{miniframes}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, arrows, arrows.meta, shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  fitting node/.style={
    inner sep=0pt,
    fill=none,
    draw=none,
    reset transform,
    fit={(\pgf@pathminx,\pgf@pathminy) (\pgf@pathmaxx,\pgf@pathmaxy)}
  },
  reset transform/.code={\pgftransformreset}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Input
\draw[black, fill=blue!10, xstep=1, ystep=1, yshift=-10, xshift=30,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1, scale=0.25] (1,1) grid (6,6) rectangle (1,1);  
\draw[yshift=-10, xshift=30,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1, scale=0.25, black, thin, dashed, xstep=1, ystep=1] (0,0) grid (7,7);
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,5} {
%Filter
\draw[yshift=-10, xshift=30,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1, scale=0.25, fill=black!50, opacity=0.4] (\x,0) rectangle (3,3) node[fitting node] (filtering) {};
%Init result position
\draw[yshift=35, xshift=40,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1, scale=0.25, fill=black!50, opacity=0.4] (0,0) rectangle (1,1) node[fitting node] (result) {};

\foreach \coord in {north, south, west, east} {
    \draw (result.\coord) -- (filtering.\coord);
}

%Feature map
\draw[yshift=35, xshift=40,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1, scale=0.25, black, fill=blue!30, xstep=1, ystep=1] (0,0) grid (5,5) rectangle (0,0);
\draw[yshift=35, xshift=40,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1, scale=0.25, fill=black!50, opacity=0.5] (\x,0) rectangle (1,1) node[fitting node] (result) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is an update after `mxnc baud` answer :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %Input
    \draw[black, fill=blue!10, xstep=1, ystep=1, yshift=-10, xshift=30,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1, scale=0.25] (1,1) grid (6,6) rectangle (1,1);  
    \draw[yshift=-10, xshift=30,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1, scale=0.25, black, thin, dashed, xstep=1, ystep=1] (0,0) grid (7,7);
    \begin{animateinline}[poster=first, controls=true, autoplay=false]{4}
        \multiframe{5}{npos=0+1}{%
            \tikz{%
                \useasboundingbox (0,0)rectangle(10,10);
                %Filter
                \draw[yshift=-10, xshift=30,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1, scale=0.25, fill=black!50, opacity=0.4] (\npos,0) rectangle (3,3) node[fitting node] (filtering) {};
                %Init result position
                \draw[yshift=35, xshift=40,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1, scale=0.25, fill=black!50, opacity=0.4] (0,0) rectangle (1,1) node[fitting node] (result) {};
                \foreach \coord in {north, south, west, east} {%
                    \draw (result.\coord) -- (filtering.\coord);
                }
                %Feature map
                \draw[yshift=35, xshift=40,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1, scale=0.25, black, fill=blue!30, xstep=1, ystep=1] (0,0) grid (5,5) rectangle (0,0);
                \draw[yshift=35, xshift=40,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1, scale=0.25, fill=black!50, opacity=0.5] (\npos,0) rectangle (1,1) node[fitting node] (result) {};
            }
        }
    \end{animateinline}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And here is the error I have :

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
```

Comment: Note that you surely will have to specify a `bounding box` that embraces your picture.

Comment: same error with bounding box

Comment: Ok, the code I wrote seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the animate documentation ?

A simple exmaple of how include tikz picture inside animate env is below :

```
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{animateinline}[poster=first,controls]{10}
        \multiframe{11}{npos=0+1}{%
        \tikz{%
            \useasboundingbox (-1,-1)rectangle(11,1);
            \draw(0,0)--(\npos,0)node[above]{$A$};
            }
        }
    \end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It should work now :

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},xcolor=table,t, compress]{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false, compress]{miniframes}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, arrows, arrows.meta, shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  fitting node/.style={
    inner sep=0pt,
    fill=none,
    draw=none,
    reset transform,
    fit={(\pgf@pathminx,\pgf@pathminy) (\pgf@pathmaxx,\pgf@pathmaxy)}
  },
  reset transform/.code={\pgftransformreset}
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[poster=first, controls=true, autoplay=false]{4}
\multiframe{5}{npos=0+1}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %Input
    \draw[black, fill=blue!10, xstep=1, ystep=1, yshift=-10, xshift=30,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1, scale=0.25] (1,1) grid (6,6) rectangle (1,1);  
    \draw[yshift=-10, xshift=30,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1, scale=0.25, black, thin, dashed, xstep=1, ystep=1] (0,0) grid (7,7);
                %Filter
\draw[yshift=-10, xshift=30,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1, scale=0.25, fill=black!50, opacity=0.4] (\npos,0) rectangle (3,3) node[fitting node] (filtering) {};
                %Init result position
\draw[yshift=35, xshift=40,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1, scale=0.25, fill=black!50, opacity=0.4] (0,0) rectangle (1,1) node[fitting node] (result) {};
\foreach \coord in {north, south, west, east} {\draw (result.\coord) -- (filtering.\coord);}
                %Feature map
\draw[yshift=35, xshift=40,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1, scale=0.25, black, fill=blue!30, xstep=1, ystep=1] (0,0) grid (5,5) rectangle (0,0);
\draw[yshift=35, xshift=40,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1, scale=0.25, fill=black!50, opacity=0.5] (\npos,0) rectangle (1,1) node[fitting node] (result) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
            }
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I can't succeed to make animateinline work.
I've this error : `! Package animate Error: Contents of first frame must not have zero width.`

Comment: Ok, so I've adapter your code to mine, and I have now this error :
`! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].`

Comment: Ok, would you let us see your code ?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the new code

Comment: Ok there are some mistakes you're not nesting the environement correctly, I think I have fixed some issues : look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks ! So now the animation is working. Anyway I have to fix some things because its not drawing elements as I want.
Thank you for your help with the animation

Comment: Ok ! then it's a good starting point @Lionel hopefully you will make it, it looks to be a decent animation.

Comment: yes it's a good start :). Anyway, I can't figure out why for each new position, the previous rectangles are still displayed

Comment: I have simplified the code to have just the upper grid displayed. You can see that the second, third and fourth cells are displayed together. When the fourth appears, the previous ones should disappear, no ?

https://gyazo.com/e30dcc5d3896d0bef060152c69aea5be

Comment: I can't play the animation from the link you gave. You want some cells to disapear when others are displayed ?

Comment: Yes, one by one, so at the end, all the cells have appeared one time

Comment: can't succeed to store the animation in a gif :( but you can see that there is 4 cells in gray (corresponding to 4 positions of a rectangle in the code)

Comment: and it's strange because the first one disappear !

Comment: Ok, my definition of the rectangle size was wrong !
`\draw[yshift=35, xshift=40,yslant=-0.5,xslant=1, scale=0.25, fill=black!50, opacity=0.5] (\npos,0) rectangle (\npos+1,0+1) node[fitting node] (result) {};` that's better now ! :)

Comment: Ow ok does it fix the problem ?

Comment: yes.

Now I'm looking how to swath different columns of the grid. I will post the final code when everything will work as wanted